# Не приходит результат ajax запроса

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Есть форма, которая отправляет данные в php файл через ajax запрос. Проблема в том, что в результате выводится в всплывающее окно фрагмент HTML кода главной страницы, а должна выводится строка из файла php

HTML

```
            <form id="form_vk">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="client_name">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Ссылка на вашу страницу в vk" name="client_vk">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Ваш e-mail" name="client_email">
                <button type="submit" id="button_vk">Записаться</button>
            </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['client_name'])){
       echo "<center> Спасибо за отправку вашего сообщения! </center>";
   }
?>
```

JavaScript

```
 $("#button_vk").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        URL: '../sendmail.php',
        data: $('#form_vk').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Использую локальный сервер - XAMPP

Выводится такое сообщение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: '../sendmail.php' ??

Comment: common.js находится в папке js, а файл sendmail.php находится в корне проекта

Comment: @user207012 уберите точки эти.

Comment: все равно выдает такое же сообщение с фрагментом кода

Comment: местоположение файла с javascript-ом не имеет значения

Comment: URL: 'sendmail.php', теперь так

Comment: @user207012 смотрите куда идет запрос. проверьте все. просто из неоткуда ничего не берется

Comment: но результат такой же

Comment: адрес страницы с формой - какой?

Comment: это index.php, то бишь в корне находится

Comment: Chrome (ну и не только) -> Ctrl+Shift+I -> вкладка Network после клика, ищите ваш запрос в списке (`sendmail.php`), нашли? жмите на строку, скидывайте сюда первые строки, в этом же окне, открывайте вкладку Response, копипастим сюда же.

Comment: А смысл копипастить сюда, когда в ответ приходит целиком страница? Автор, PHP из какого файла предоставлен? При получении данных от формы и показа сообщения пользователю, делайте `exit;`, тогда остальная страница не будет возвращаться в ответе.

Comment: Ну, я полагаю, смысл таки есть, т.к. ответом может быть и кастомная 500-я (или там 404-я) страница, а это уже другая история.  А вообще - да, первое что приходит в голову - отсутствие die/exit и полный вывод всего.

Answer (score 1):

dataType укажите в параметрах json.

Сделать проще можно так:
PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['client_name'])) {
    echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'message' => "Спасибо за отправку сообщения"]);
}
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'tst.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        if(result.success === true) {
            alert(result.message);
        }
    }
});
```